# List of Errors in Fix's Principles of Brewing Science

Tags: books

Several sources claim that the Fix classic *Principles of Brewing Science* has several errors; however, there doesn't seem to be any comprehensive list of what is incorrect.

Where can I find a complete list of the errata for this book?

Comment: You know, there are two editions. Maybe the 2nd one is better?

Comment: could be, I have the second edition so that's hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

Errata imply that the author and/or the publisher have accepted the criticism as valid error in the book.  I don't think you're going to find that's the case, partially because the book has been out of print for a long time, and the author has passed away.  You could always [contact Kristi Switzer](http://www.brewerspublications.com/contact-us/) and ask her directly.

On a side note, can you cite any sources for your claim the book has several errors?

Comment: +1 good insight. I knew Mr Fix had passed on, but I didn't realise it required his consent to publish errata.